# Linux Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Is there any way to get the linux terminal on Mac OS X? Without using any tool like Homebrew, can the same commands be executed effectively in Mac OS X also?

Comment: Huh? OS X isn't Linux, it's OS X. Press `Cmd+Spacebar` (to start Spotlight search) and start typing `Terminal`. Hit `Enter` when it guesses `Terminal` and start typing commands into your OSX Terminal.

Comment: Unix, yes. Linux, no. Not without a tool like Homebrew.

Comment: Darrick Herwehe : please be more precise.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe what if we have brew installed.

Comment: @SahilBabbar I can't answer that, because I don't use homebrew. What I meant by Unix/Linux is both Mac OS and Linux have Unix underlying the system, but each have made their own changes on top of it. So, you can use all of the commands that are part of Unix on mac and Linux, but you cannot use Linux-specific commands on mac.